# Update Preview issue in Experience Manager, Using Tridion 2013 SP1, DD4T 2.0 (JAVA)

Tags: experience-manager, ambient-data-framework

When I click on update preview it try to refresh the page and display nothing, goes blank. Entries are created in session preview database tables. FILEPATH is null for all rows in table PREVIEW_SESSION_ITEMS. on checking staging website cd_core logs (DEBUG mode) I found only one suspicious entry - No claim store!!! Ambient framework is probably not enabled!

I have gone through the existing threads raised on this issue and have verified cd_ambient.xml, cd_dynamic.xml and web.xml for staging website as well as preview webservice, all are correct.

Staging website cd_core logs are below:

```
2015-08-26 14:43:13,518 DEBUG AbstractMethodHandler - Original publication ID for write method parameter [non_entity] is 235.
2015-08-26 14:43:13,518 DEBUG AbstractMethodHandler - Session-publication ID for write method parameter [non_entity] is 285.
2015-08-26 14:43:13,518 TRACE MethodHandlerUtils - Calling method 'findByPrimaryKey' of the original DAO.
2015-08-26 14:43:13,522 TRACE JPABaseDAO - [ActionTimer] Query List Result time: 3953436 nanoseconds (3.953436 milliseconds)
2015-08-26 14:43:13,523 DEBUG ReadMethodHandler - Session returned a result for method: findByPrimaryKey.
2015-08-26 14:43:13,523 TRACE MethodHandlerUtils - Detaching object from any sessions.
2015-08-26 14:43:13,523 TRACE MethodHandlerUtils - Object to detach is of type com.tridion.storage.ComponentPresentationMeta.
2015-08-26 14:43:13,525 TRACE MethodHandlerUtils - Injecting real publicationId into object of type com.tridion.storage.ComponentPresentationMeta.
2015-08-26 14:43:13,525 TRACE MethodHandlerUtils - Not allowed to inject realPublicationId for class 'com.tridion.storage.ComponentPresentationMeta' and property 'templateMeta'.
2015-08-26 14:43:13,525 DEBUG SessionManagerImpl - Activity on session: e453cbc1-ffca-4b27-a519-e84112bf4dd1, extending session lifetime until: Wed Aug 26 14:45:13 CDT 2015.
2015-08-26 14:43:13,526 DEBUG JPAPreviewSessionDAO - Retrieving PreviewSession by sessionId: e453cbc1-ffca-4b27-a519-e84112bf4dd1
2015-08-26 14:43:13,527 TRACE JPABaseDAO - [ActionTimer] Query List Result time: 1643726 nanoseconds (1.643726 milliseconds)
2015-08-26 14:43:13,528 DEBUG SessionServiceImpl - PreviewSession already exists, updating with PreviewSession [sessionId=e453cbc1-ffca-4b27-a519-e84112bf4dd1, expirationDate=Wed Aug 26 14:45:13 CDT 2015]
2015-08-26 14:43:13,528 DEBUG JPAPreviewSessionDAO - Updating PreviewSession: PreviewSession [sessionId=e453cbc1-ffca-4b27-a519-e84112bf4dd1, expirationDate=Wed Aug 26 14:45:13 CDT 2015]
2015-08-26 14:43:13,545 DEBUG WebContext - setCurrentClaimStore: null, thread: tomcat-request-13
2015-08-26 14:43:13,548 DEBUG SessionManagerImpl - No claim store!!! Ambient framework is probably not enabled!
2015-08-26 14:43:13,548 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findById' while not in session.
2015-08-26 14:43:13,548 TRACE MethodHandlerUtils - Calling method 'findById' of the original DAO.
2015-08-26 14:43:13,551 TRACE JPABaseDAO - [ActionTimer] Query List Result time: 2591871 nanoseconds (2.591871 milliseconds)
2015-08-26 14:43:13,551 DEBUG SessionManagerImpl - No claim store!!! Ambient framework is probably not enabled!
2015-08-26 14:43:13,551 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByPageURL' while not in session.
2015-08-26 14:43:13,551 TRACE MethodHandlerUtils - Calling method 'findByPageURL' of the original DAO.
2015-08-26 14:43:13,553 TRACE JPABaseDAO - [ActionTimer] Query List Result time: 1098256 nanoseconds (1.098256 milliseconds)
2015-08-26 14:44:08,406 TRACE SessionManagerImpl - Performing cleanup of old sessions.
2015-08-26 14:44:08,406 TRACE JPAPreviewSessionDAO - Retrieving all expired sessions.
2015-08-26 14:44:08,409 TRACE JPABaseDAO - [ActionTimer] Query List Result time: 2925934 nanoseconds (2.925934 milliseconds)
2015-08-26 14:44:08,412 TRACE JPABaseDAO - [ActionTimer] Query List Result time: 2104687 nanoseconds (2.104687 milliseconds)
2015-08-26 14:44:08,412 TRACE SessionServiceImpl - The closest time for a session to expire is: 2015-08-26 14:44:56.644
2015-08-26 14:44:08,413 TRACE SessionsCleanerMonitor - Sleeping for 48235 milliseconds
```

Comment: Troubleshooting XPM dynamic preview is probably the hardest infrastructure job you can get in the Tridion world; if you don't have any experience with it I wholeheartedly suggest you hire someone who does. Solving an issue like this via SE is virtually impossible.

Answer (score 2):

1) Have you verified on your staging website that the appropriate session preview claim(s) are present in the ADF? You can find [a java page to dump the contents of the claimstore here](https://github.com/TridionPractice/tridion-practice/blob/master/AmbientDataFramework/ClaimStore.jsp).

2) Are you using DXA/DD4T or published JSP pages? The latter require a filter to be present in your web.xml configuration to stream page content to disk from the preview database. If this is all properly configured you would see temporary files on your filesystem next to your original page. If these don't appear it usually indicates a permissions problem where the web application isn't allowed to write to it's own root directory (which is required for the filter to work normally).